# Mooring or docking

Tags: word-choice

When passenger ship comes in harbor what does it do - mooring or docking? Is there any special term for this action?

Comment: I would say the ship docked. After that it was moored.

Comment: To my mind *mooring* is more applicable to small boats and yachts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://www.theshippinglawblog.com/, a docked ship is one connected to a dock, the business area of a pier.  A moored ship is one that is secured by ropes to a permanent fixture.  Usually this word describes ships "at moorings," areas of a harbor where ships and boats are tied to a fixed object on the seabed, like a large concrete block.  A buoy is tied to the block and the ship ties to the buoy.

So a docked ship is moored, but a moored ship isn't necessarily docked.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some definitions focussed more on private vessels (boats and yachts etc) from UltimateBerths.com

**Definition of Marina Berths & Moorings**

Berth/Slip - (Generally called Berths in Europe and Slips in the USA)
Any designated place to come to come to rest for a vessel, usually but not always attached to something solid. A place between two piers to dock a vessel. Most often seen in marinas. In marinas some berths/slips don't actually have piers alongside but only a couple of piles or a buoy to which to secure one end of the vessel; the vessel is boarded from the other end which will face a pier. (usually stern to)

**Mooring -**

In the usual context of small boats and yachts, *strictly speaking* a mooring is permission from the town to place the weight, chain, buoy etc commonly called a mooring in a designated place so as to moor your boat there. In common usage it's such a weight or anchor, a swivel, chain or heavy line leading up to a buoy and a "mooring pennant" These moorings are used instead of temporary anchors because they have considerably more holding power, cause less damage to the marine environment, and are convenient. They are sometimes known as 'swing moorings.' Moorings are also occasionally used to hold floating docks in place.

**Piling -**

Pile moorings are poles driven into the bottom of the waterway with their tops above the water. Vessels then tie mooring lines to two or four piles to fix their position between those piles. Strictly speaking a structure composed of piles, which are telephone poles or other such long thin items driven into the ground. Many tall buildings are actually supported by many long pilings beneath them. Working around boats, a pile is usually called a piling, and a set of pilings pulled and cabled together to form a sturdier structure than can be obtained with a single piling is called a dolphin. Whether single pilings or dolphins, these stand out in the water to take mooring lines from a vessel, to support a navigational marker called a beacon, to give pelicans and shag a place to stand.

Ref: [www.ultimateberths.com](http://www.ultimateberths.com)